# If $u\left(x\right)\leq c+\int_{0}^{x}u\left(t\right)v\left(t\right)dt$ then $u\left(x\right)\leq c\exp\left(\int_{0}^{x}v\left(t\right)dt\right).$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration, integral-inequality

I'm trying to solve the next problem: Let $c\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$and
$u,v$ be continuous and postive functions from $\mathbb{R}_{+}$
to $\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$, $u\left(x\right)\leq c+\int_{0}^{x}u\left(t\right)v\left(t\right)dt$.
Prove that $u\left(x\right)\leq c\cdot\exp\left(\int_{0}^{x}v\left(t\right)dt\right)$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$.

Using the first inequality, $u\left(x\right)\leq c+\int_{0}^{x}u\left(t\right)v\left(t\right)dt$,
taking exponential in both sides, we have that 
$$
\exp u\left(x\right)\leq\exp\left(c+\int_{0}^{x}u\left(t\right)v\left(t\right)dt\right)=\exp c\cdot\exp\left(\int_{0}^{x}u\left(t\right)v\left(t\right)dt\right).
$$

Using the fact that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ $x\leq\exp x$, we have
that $u\left(x\right)\leq\exp c\cdot\exp\left(\int_{0}^{x}u\left(t\right)v\left(t\right)dt\right)$.
Also using a kind of intermediate value theorem for integrals I have
for the integral $\int_{0}^{x}u\left(t\right)v\left(t\right)dt$,
that there exists $w\in\left[0,x\right]$ ($w$ could depend on $x$)
such that $\int_{0}^{x}u\left(t\right)v\left(t\right)dt=u\left(w\right)\cdot\int_{0}^{x}v\left(t\right)dt$.
I have tried that, but I couldn't obtain the inequality
that we have to prove in the problem. Could you help me or give me
some suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: That is [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grönwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions) – there is also a proof in that article.

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487307/intuition-of-gronwall-lemma